How is the universal generalization rule used?
The following deduction seems correct:
$(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$
$\forall x (x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$
But the following deduction is obviously incorrect:
$x+1=2$
$\forall x (x+1)=2$
Did I use the universal generalization rule in a wrong way?

The crucial point is that the variable $x$ you introduce when saying "let $x$ be an arbitrary ..." needs to be not used yet. Think about it this way: "Suppose $x$ is a foo. Let  be an arbitrary blah such that ..." is clearly bonkers in a way that "Suppose  is a foo. Let $y$ be an arbitrary blah such that ..." isn't.
The exact details of how this plays out formally will depend on what proof system you use; I'll describe how it works for one system in particular. In any case, the relevant term is "free occurrence" - the variable we want to later generalize has to not occur freely in the hypotheses.

Sequent calculus
Personally this is my favorite (type of) system right now. A sequent is an expression $\Gamma\vdash\delta$ where $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas and $\delta$ is a single formula; it's read as "From $\Gamma$ we can prove $\delta$." When $\Gamma$ consists of a single formula we usually ignore curly braces, writing "$\gamma\vdash\delta$" for "$\{\gamma\}\vdash\delta$."
(Actually sequents can be more general than that, but I'm ignoring that for the moment; sequents of the above type will be fine for us.)
Universal generalization is a rule about sequents: it says that having already established $\Gamma\vdash\delta$ we can further establish $\Gamma\vdash\forall x\delta$ as long as the variable $x$ did not occur freely in $\Gamma$. So for instance $$x=2\vdash x=2$$ is a correct sequent (duh!) but $$x=2\vdash \forall x(x=2)$$ is not, since the variable $x$ was used freely in the hypothesis in the original sequent.
Sequent structure is generally implicit in natural language. Your first example can be thought of as going from the correct sequent $$A\vdash (x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$$ to the correct sequent $$A\vdash \forall x((x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1),$$ where $A$ is some reasonable set of axioms for algebra. In particular, $A$ probably consists entirely of sentences (= formulas without free variables).
What about your second example? Well, we have to look for the implicit context giving rise to $$x+1=2.$$ This definitely didn't come from pure rules of algebra, that is, we're not claiming $A\vdash x+1=2$ is a correct sequent where $A$ is as above. Instead, we (presumably!) started with some hypotheses about this specific $x$. That means we're looking at a sequent of the form $$A\cup B\vdash x+1=2$$ where $A$ is as above and $B$ is a set of formulas in which the variable $x$ occurs freely (something like "$x+7=8$" might well be an element of $B$). But that free occurrence prevents us from using universal generalization.

Going back to the language at the top of this answer, the point is that "Suppose $x$ is a foo" is (an element of) our $\Gamma$, and the free occurrence of $x$ in that formula prevents us from using $x$ as the universally-generalized variable later on.

What are some advantages that sequent calculus has over natural deduction?

@PW_246 I like the clarity that sequents, as objects distinct from formulas themselves, provide; but ultimately it's just a matter of taste.

So, when we are about to infer $\forall x \delta$ from $\delta$, we should first find the assumptions of $\delta$, i.e., $\Gamma$, we need to ensure $\Gamma \vdash \delta$ is correct, and we should check if x is free in $\Gamma$, if all successful, we can conclude $\forall x \delta$. But this is very different from our daily use of the universal generalization rule in math proof, which often takes the form of "let xx be an arbitrary yy, ..., we prove xx has the property of P, so for all zz of yy, zz has the property of P". How do you map this to the sequent calculus?

@William The crucial point is that the variable $x$ you introduce when saying "let $x$ be an arbitrary ..." needs to be not used yet - and this corresponds exactly to the requirement that $x$ not occur freely in $\Gamma$. Think about it this way: "Suppose $x$ is a foo. Let $x$ be an arbitrary blah such that ..." is clearly bonkers in a way that "Suppose $x$ is a foo. Let $y$ be an arbitrary blah such that ..." isn't; the point is that "$x$ is a foo" is our $\Gamma$, and the free occurrence of $x$ there constrains what variables we can introduce if we want to later use universal generalization.

@William I've folded this in to the answer itself.

I'm still not clear about this problem. I did not say there is some A such that $A\vdash x+1=2$. In fact, I am not familiar with sequent calculus and use the fitch-style natural deduction system, which I can write x+1=2 on the first line as an assumption and write $\forall x x+1=2$ on the second line according to the universal generalization rule applied to line 1. It seems nothing can stop me from doing this. The UG rule requires nothing but the x on the first line is a fresh free variable or constant, which is satisfied because there is no line before the first line.


The following deduction seems correct:
$(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$
$\forall x (x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$

In a mathematical proof such as this, you would have to specify the domain, say, the set of real number $R$.
$x \in R~~~~$ (Initial premise)
$\vdots$
$(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1~~~~$ (Follows from intital premise)
$x \in R  \implies (x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1~~~~$ (Discharging the initial premise)
$\forall x: [x\in R \implies (x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1]~~~~$ (Generalizing, as required)
Alternatively...
$\forall x \in R: (x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$

But the following deduction is obviously incorrect:
$x+1=2$
$\forall x (x+1)=2$

We cannot infer from $x\in R~$ that $x+1 =2$.

I didn't infer from $x\in R$ that $x+1=2$. I use the fitch-style natural deduction system, which I can write x+1=2 on the first line as an assumption and write $\forall x x+1=2$ on the second line according to the universal generalization rule applied to line 1. It seems nothing can stop me from doing this. The UG rule requires nothing but the x on the first line is a fresh free variable or constant, which is satisfied because there is no line before the first line.

@William I myself found the various presentations of the rule for universal generalization to be very confusing. I had to reverse engineer various proofs to formulate my own rule to program it for my proof checker. It works quite nicely, but I still don't understand other presentations of the rule! I'm guessing, you probably have to discharge your initial premise before generalizing in the Fitch system.


Did I use the universal generalization rule in a wrong way?

The first one of your formulas, supposedly, is an identity, whence the universal quantifier is implied.  The second one is an equation, whence an existential quantifier is rather implied.
Indeed, in either case, you are not generalizing: the initial formulas, read strictly, are just not closed formulas.

Did you mean we can only generalize closed formulas(sentences), not open formulas? Then the to-be-generalized sentence includes a constant?

@William  Sorry, my answer is in fact not very much to the point.  In general, an open formula is simply not a proposition, so it makes no sense to ask if it is true or false, and the statements you presented are simply not fully qualified mathematical statements: the first one wants universal quantification, the second makes sense as an equation and wants existential quantification (could be closed with a universal, too, but then it would be false).  That said, natural deduction does have open formulas, so in that specific sense, you should look at others' answers.
